# How can an app communicate across user accounts?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, wmi, communication

Do you know how a C# app can communicate with another C# app running on another Windows user account logged in at the same time?

One of my clients is using [Windows MultiPoint Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_MultiPoint_Server) via thin clients. We need some way for an app to communicate across user accounts. How can this be done with the lowest data latency? I'm aware of techniques like TCP sockets, WMI, [MSMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C), etc. But across users accounts?

Comment: It depends to the requirement. **•** For example a simple solution can be writing on file system and using `FileSystemWatcher`. You can use a single file share or specific files for each client based on requirement **•** Another option can be using self hosted WCF service, each instance register itself on a specific port and communicate with other instances; in this case you can have a predefined user-port mapping in a central point like a shared file or a database.

Comment: I need it to be as fast and low-latency as possible. Events must be sent and received in <1ms. I'm currently looking into MSMQ but open to ideas.

Comment: Other options to consider are memory mapped files and named pipes.

Answer (score 1):

If speed and latency is a concern then you can use UDP sockets bound to localhost, since it's stateless you can have as many instances as you need sending and receiving data locally across user accounts and sessions.